# Return to main latex file after correcting error in GVim

Tags: vim, macros, latex, recompile

Using the vim-latexsuite for Gvim, I am editing a fairly large document.
It consists of a main document that contains \begin{document}, \end{document} etc.
In between there are a lot of sections that are written in another documents and imported with `\input{blahblah}`.

The problem is that when I compile using `\ll` there is an error in one of the imported documents. This document is opened in the current tab along with the errorlog, etc. This is of course done so that I can correct the error easily.

...but after correcting the error, I am now positioned in another document in the tab that was previously my main document. This document does not have the preamble and therefore I have to reopen the main document in order to recompile to see if my correction works.

It seems to me that i should be easy to recompile on the spot after I have corrected the error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the cuff it seems like <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> could be of use as long as the main document is still open as a buffer. See `:help CTRL-o` for more information on how this works. You can check this with `:ls` and see if the buffer shows up.

Comment: Works well, thanks a bunch. Will read upon the use of buffers.